# How should perceptron work with 0 inputs (for AND/OR)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am trying to make a simple perceptron to perform logical AND but I do not know how to solve the 0 input issue.

weight+=error*learning_rate*input

Also when input is 0, no matter what the error was, the weight will not change.

And one more question, in general, when training the perceptron, can I repeat the examples for both sets (lets say have one for 0 and one for 1) or do they need to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting and very important insight. That's why you usually should have a bias in a neural network.

Imagine the decision surface of a perceptron as a line of the form

y = w*x+b

When you remove the b (bias) from the equation, you will only be able to learn lines that pass (0, 0).

Comment: I have read about the bias and from the example, they introduced that as a new input with its own weight. But in that case, weights for the first 2 inputs will still not change.

Comment: No, they generally won't change because they do not have to change when the bias is available. The bias shifts the decision surface so that x=0 is mapped to the correct y.

Comment: HM but in that case, how the AND can work? If I feed my perceptron with 0,0 I get 1, because the bias is 0.1. And I can train only 1,1=1 and 0,0=0.

Comment: Imagine your problem in a two-dimensional plane: you've got the points (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1). x2 = -1*x1+1.5 should generate a line that separates the two classes, so 0 = -x1 -x2 + 1.5 defines your decision surface, i. e. take the weights (w1=-1, w2=-1) and the bias 1.5. That would work. On the other hand, what would change if w2=-0.2? (Of course you cannot start with w1=0 and w2=0 which is not recommended in general.)